# Initialise array using Array.ForEach - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, arrays

I have an array of RichTextBoxes and I would like to initialise them using Array.ForEach.

I have made the following attempt with no success:

```
Dim aRTB(5) as RichTextBox
Array.ForEach(aRTB, Function() New RichTextBox)
```

This code was the only one to make it past the compiler however it doesn't initialise any part of the array.

Code which failed to past the compiler includes:

```
Array.ForEach(aRTB, Function() Return New RichTextBox)
Array.ForEach(aRTB, Function(rtb as RichTextBox) rtb = New RichTextBox)
```

I realise I could easily set up a a regular loop (For, Do, While) to perform the same action however I would like to see if this way can work.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have an array of RichTextBoxes and I would like to initialise them using Array.ForEach.

You cannot. [Array.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2.aspx) performs an action on every element of the array, i.e., it passes the elements of the array to your function a parameter:

```
Array.ForEach(aRTB, Sub(rtb as RichTextBox) ...do something with rtb...)
```

The parameter is `ByVal`, i.e., you cannot use this to *change* the contents of the array:

```
Array.ForEach(aRTB, Sub(ByRef rtb as RichTextBox) rtb = New RichTextBox())
' Yields compilation error: 
' Nested sub does not have a signature that is compatible 
' with delegate 'System.Action(Of RichTextBox)
```

Since your array is initially empty, you can't do anything useful with Array.ForEach on it.

Sorry, but you will have to use a classic `For` loop for this:

```
For i = 0 To 5
    aRTB(i) = New RichTextBox()
Next
```

<sub>The `0 To 5` is not a typo... in VB.NET array declarations specify the upper bound, not the size.</sub>

Comment: Aww that's too bad, I've always liked for loops anyway :) and thank you for the explanation!